# She must have had her hair cut

Tags: causatives

*She must have had her hair cut.*

Just wanna ask whether the sentence above is grammatically OK. I try to use the causative and the past tense for the modal verbs ("must have done"). I want to express that I am convinced that she used the services of the hairdresser.

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to me.

> Her hair looks different. She must have had her hair cut.